# How can I show all countries in UIcomponent dropdown?

Tags: magento2

```
<field name="country_id">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
<item name="options" xsi:type="object"></item><item name="config" xsi:type="array">
<item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
<item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Country</item>
<item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
<item name="source" xsi:type="string">ModuleName</item>
<item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">country_id</item>
<item name="default" xsi:type="string">10</item>
<item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
<item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
</item>
</item>
</argument>
</field>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<field name="country_id">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
<item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</item>
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
<item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
<item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Country</item>
<item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
<item name="source" xsi:type="string">store</item>
<item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
<item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">country_id</item>
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/country</item>
<item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
<item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
</item>
</item>
</argument>
</field>
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I found the solution in this way, hope it will be helpful for someone

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below codes

```
  <field name="manage_stock">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Manage Stock</item>
                            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                            <item name="rawOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">manage_stock</item>
                            <item name="scopeLabel" xsi:type="string">[GLOBAL]</item>
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="object">Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Source\StockConfiguration</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</item>
                    </argument>
                </field>
```

***Let me know if face issue***

Comment: Thanks guys, I found the solution in this way, hope it will be helpful for someone

Comment: welcome!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<field name="country_id" formElement="select">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">country_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <visible>false</visible>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            </validation>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Country</label>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <select>
                <settings>
                    <options class="Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\Collection"/>
                </settings>
            </select>
        </formElements>
    </field>
```